# FETCH_ASSOC removes indexes in the wrong array

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a small web application and I am running on two arrays - one retrieved by simplexml_load_file and the other generated by query to database. I have a little problem with the latter - I need to create an associative array that I can reference through indexes. For that I do something like that.

```
$stmt->execute();
$db = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The array should therefore look like this:

```
Array (
['element'] => value,
)
```

It looks like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
['element'] => value,
)
)
```

The only thing I noticed was that in the query the records are created so

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
['element'] => value,
[0] => value
)
)
```

My solution removes indexes inside the first array, in this example it will remove the line `[0] => value`, although the main index will remain. How can I change this to result in a full associative associative array? I mention that I want to display all the records from the query, the same fetch () works, although it displays one record (last) from the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

From

```
$db = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

To

```
$db = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`PDOStatement::fetch` — Fetches the next row from a result set

While `PDOStatement::fetchAll` — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows

Comment: fetch() method returns only one record from database - i need all records

Comment: @sauero : provide example of 2-3 rows  ?

Answer (score 0):

The 0 means row one. If you want to process only one row use the current function on the array which will give you expected results